# Absolute values of algebraic integers

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

I'm trying to understand Lemma 2.13 in the paper [Seshadri constants, Diophantine approximation, and Roth's Theorem for arbitrary varieties](https://arxiv.org/abs/1306.2976).

The setup is as follows: $k$ is a number field and $v$ is a finite place of $k$ with corresponding prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}\subset \mathcal{O}_k$. The claim is that since the class number is finite, we can take some large power $\mathfrak{p}^n$ such that this ideal is prinicipal with generator $b$, such that $|b|_w=1$ for all finite places $w\neq v$ and $|b|_w>1$ for all infinite places.

I do not understand why the last part is true. To me it is clear the when $n$ is greater or equal to the class number $\mathfrak{p}^n$ is principal with generator $b$ and since $b \in \mathfrak{p}$ it follows that  $|b|_v<1$ and $|b|_w=1$ for $w$ finite. However I have no idea how to get the requirement on the infinite places. The authors suggest that we can achieves this by increasing $n$ and multiplying by units. Increasing $n$, doesn't increase the absolute value if $|b|_w<1$ then $|b^n|_w=|b|_w^n<1$ and I have no idea about how archimedean absolute values of units behave. I'm suspecting that maybe $b$ is allowed to be in $k$ and we are allowed to multiply by units in $k^\times$ but I'm not so sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\sigma_1,\dots,\sigma_{r_1}$ be the real places of $K$ and let $\tau_1,\dots,\tau_{r_2}$ be the complex places of $K$, and consider the homomorphism
$$\alpha\colon K^\times\to\mathbb R^{r_1+r_2}:u\mapsto (\log|\sigma_i(u)|,2\log|\tau_j(u)|)_{i\le r_1,j\le r_2}.$$
Then the product formula tells us the image of $\mathcal O_K^\times$ lands in the subspace $V$ consisting of $(x_i,y_j)_{i\le r_1,j\le r_2}$ such that $\sum_{i=1}^{r_1}x_i+\sum_{j=1}^{r_2}y_j=0$. Moreover, Dirichlet's unit theorem tells us $\alpha(\mathcal O_K^\times)\subset V$ is a lattice.

We know by the product formula that $\alpha(b)$ lands in subspace $\sum_{i=1}^{r_1}x_i+\sum_{j=1}^{r_2}y_j>0$. So now it is an exercise in the geometry of lattices to see that there is an integer $N\gg0$ and $\lambda$ in the lattice $\alpha(\mathcal O_K^\times)$ such that $N\alpha(b)+\lambda$ lands in $\mathbb R_{>0}^{r_1+r_2}$.

> **Hint:** We know $\{\lambda/N:\lambda\in\alpha(\mathcal O_K^\times),N>0\}=\alpha(\mathcal O_K^\times)\otimes_{\mathbb Z}\mathbb Q\subset V$ is dense.

Comment: I will think about your answer. You mention that $\alpha$ extends to $K^\times$, is this relevant in your argument?

Comment: I just need it to define $\alpha(b)$. Sorry, maybe I should have defined $\alpha$ on $K^\times$ and restricted to $\mathcal O_K^\times$ later when I talk about Dirichlet's unit theorem.